# Цикл for во Flask

Tags: flask

В первом декораторе открываю файл, во втором нужно из импортированной библиотеки Faker рандомно выбить имя и мейл и вывести их 10 раз.
Подскажите что не так делаю в цикле for

```
from flask import Flask                                                    
from faker import Faker                                                    

app = Flask(__name__)                                                      
fake = Faker()    


@app.route('/')                                                            
def read_file():                                                           
    f = open('/Users/dev/Desktop/new_project/requiremets.txt','r')         
    f.read()                                                               
    return f.read()                                                        


@app.route('/user')                                                        
def user():                                                                
    name = fake.name()                                                     
    email = fake.email()                                                   
    single = {'name':name, 'email':email}                                  
    for _ in range(10):                                                    
        return single                                                      


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                 
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя использовать return внутри функции так как она завершиться на первой же итерации. Так же значением для возврата должна быть строка.
Кажется то что вы пытаетесь сделать можно написать без использования цикла.

```
return (str(single) + '<br>') * 10
```

Или все же использовать, но уже в шаблонах

./templates/main.html

```
{% for i in range(10) %}
{{ single }}
{% endfor %}
```

```
return render_template('main.html', single=single)
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил, спасибо!

```
@app.route('/user')
def user():
    result = []
    for _ in range(10):
        name = fake.name()
        email = fake.email()
        result.append({'name': name, 'email': email})

    return str(result)
```